# Vue3 and Vite not working properly on iPadOS

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I have a pretty weird problem, as my code runs just fine on an updated iphone(iOS 16) but not on ipad(iPadOS 16). My vue app works perfectly fine on iOS, but on iPad it is like its not executing the script scope at all. I have written some console logs to test it but it‘s not logging at all. No error or what I have programmed just nothing as if the script scope would not exist.JavaScript is enabled and the IPad is regularly used on safari. Does somebody know a special configuration for that problem?

The code is not interesting. I just have console.log(„test“) in the mounted() method. That‘s all to exclude there are any other effects which could invoke a conflict. A vue 2 app with regular builder works just fine…
I am not coming to my computer so fast, so as tiny look in my package.json. I am using vue v3.2.47 and vue-router: v4.1.6
Vite v4.3.5. These should be all interesting dependencies since this is only about console logs.